# tensorflow.contrib in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train my object detection model using this [tutorial](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model/)
However, I am getting this error

```
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\slim\nets\nasnet\nasnet.py", line 27, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib import training as contrib_training
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I understand that tensorflow.contrib is no longer used in tensorflow 2.x and I managed to fix other errors by using tf_slim but I still have problem with this line

```
from tensorflow.contrib import training as contrib_training
```

I searched for a replacement but did not succeed. Is there any replacement that I could use and achieve the same result without downgrading my tensorflow version?

Answer (score 0):

As you are already aware, **tf.contrib** is deprecated and replaced its sub-modules with **TF Slim** and **TF addons** api.

tf.contrib.training contains a few classes which are already merged by other names. You can find your specific required functionality sub-module by checking [TensorFlow 2.x APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf) list.

Please refer to this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrate_tf2) for more details.